# blank hash from rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a custom method in my rails app that looks like this below.
I have tested the sql in the rails console and it returns a hash like this id => vu.

```
  def self.vu ids
    results = User.select('tests.dpi, sum(worker) as vu')
    .joins{tests}
    .where("tests.dpi in (?)", ids)
    .group('tests.dpi')

    hash = {}
    results.each {|record| hash[record.dpi] = record.vu}
    hash
  end
```

For show in my controller I have this:

```
  def show
    ids = User.find(params[:id])
    logger.debug "test: #{ids.id}"
            #See ID at this point and SQL query runs

    vu = Hash.new
    vu =User.vu ids.id
    logger.debug "value: #{vu}"
    #Blank

    vu = vu[ids.id]
    logger.debug "value: #{vu}"
    #blank no hash value?

  end
```

I can see the SQL query running correctly, and it works in console, but it doesn't set a value in the hash? What am I obviously missing? Thank you.

Comment: Most likely it is a string. Try `vu[ids.id.to_s]` instead. If it works, please post this code to codereview.stackexchange.com, as it might need some major refactoring.

Comment: if you log inside the block `|record| hash[record.dpi] = record.vu`, do you get the right informations ?